# Implementation of scala set.contains

Tags: scala

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
/**
* Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
*/
def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

Why does this `contains` function work?

I don't get it.
How does the `()` operator return `true`/`false` about existence of this element in set?

Comment: Is a course running again? There's been a few set-as-function questions in the last day or two...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking this piece by piece, the type alias in the first line means that we can rewrite the second line as follows:

```
def contains(s: Int => Boolean, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

But `A => B` is just syntactic sugar for [`Function1[A, B]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html), so we can do more rewriting:

```
def contains(s: Function1[Int, Boolean], elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

`s(elem)` is also syntactic sugar—any time you "apply" a value to a value in this way, Scala desugars it to `s.apply(elem)`:

```
def contains(s: Function1[Int, Boolean], elem: Int): Boolean = s.apply(elem)
```

And if you look at [the `apply` method on `Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#apply(v1:T1):R) you'll see that the types line up.

So that's it—we're just representing the set as its [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and then burying that under three layers of syntactic sugar.

---

Update to address the comment: representing a set as its indicator function makes it possible to model infinite sets (and lots of other sets) much more naturally than the usual list-based representation. Suppose I want a set of all odd numbers, for example. Using the representation you have here, this is easy:

```
val odds: Set[Int] = (_ % 2 != 0)
```

Try doing the same thing with `HashSet`, for example.

Comment: thanks ,but i still don't understand, why does "s.apply(elem)" return true if elem exists, why does it return false if elem it not in set?

Comment: Updated—let me know if that doesn't make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` here is a function from `Int` to `Boolean`, so calling `s(someInt)` returns a boolean, you have of course to provide that function:

```
def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

contains({ someInt => someInt == 1 }, 1) // returns true
```