# scala filter of 2 sets

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
  def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (x => s(x) && t(x))


  def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set  = intersect(s, p)
```

I have this code.
I don't understand how does "`filter`" function be a valid one.
First of all, it uses `intersect`, but second parameter `p` is a method, not a Set as `intersect` function prototype requres.
Secondly, how does `intersect(s, p)` work as filter？

thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a set represented as a *collection*, but it's a function representation, which is a type alias `type Set = Int => Boolean`; that means you are able to use `p`, because it unifies to the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different ways of looking at the same thing. As I mentioned in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973945/334519), representing sets as their indicator functions makes lots of things more convenient, and one of those things is filtering.

Usually when we have a collection of some type `A` we can filter it using a predicate function `A => Boolean` that tells us whether or not we want to keep each element. In this case, the type of the predicate function is the same type we're using to represent the collection, and filtering is the same thing as taking the intersection of two sets.

To address your second question: `intersect` needs to return a function that will return `true` if the item is in both set `s` and set `t` and `false` otherwise. We can check that using the `apply` method on each (or in this case its syntactic sugar). The implementation is then a simple function literal `(x => s(x) && t(x))` that takes an argument `x` and returns `true` if and only if `x` is in both sets.