# Characteristic function in functional set

Tags: scala

It's a question regarding syntactic sugars in Scala functions, similar discussion could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995988/working-with-sets-as-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973770/implementation-of-scala-set-contains). Both answers give great insights, but I still cannot get my head aroud.

That is, I could not understand **how characteristic function works**?

Characteristic function (see the code below):

- s(elem)
- Set(elem)

Let's see an example,

```
object devScript extends App {
  type Set = Int => Boolean
  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

  def singletonSet1(elem: Int): Set = (x: Int) => x == elem
  def singletonSet2(elem: Int): Set = Set(elem)

  println(contains(singletonSet1(5), 5))
  println(contains(singletonSet2(5), 5))
}
```

Returns:

```
true
true
```

`singletonSet1` and `singletonSet2` have given the same result, so are they just two functions that expressing the same thing but in different forms? Moreover, without explicitly define a Boolean clause, how could a function return `true`/`false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this example is a bit confusing because there are two definitions of `Set` in scope. You define your own type alias `Set` which has a type of a function that takes `Int` and returns `Boolean`: `Int => Boolean`. On the other hand you also have `Set` from Scala collections in scope which has `apply` function which is also of the same type: `Int => Boolean`. Let's look at these types in REPL:

```
scala> singletonSet1 _
res1: Int => Set = $$Lambda$1261/1618596377@4ed90b04

scala> singletonSet2 _
res2: Int => Set = $$Lambda$1262/224661478@14f08a97

scala> Set(1).apply _
res3: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$1352/273821181@17d6b6e

// same as apply above
scala> Set(1)(_)
res4: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$1377/1981148063@4ebe0e3f

scala> singletonSet1(1)
res5: Set = $$Lambda$1230/593573468@7574d30b

scala> singletonSet1(1)(1)
res6: Boolean = true

// or similarly:
scala> singletonSet2(1)(1)
res7: Boolean = true
```

As you can see `apply`, also written as `()` conforms to the type that you need to return from your `singletonSet[1|2]` function.

You are right that both of them can be used as functions which are implemented in different forms: using closures for `singletonSet1` and using regular Scala `Set` in `singletonSet2` case.

Note that `singletonSet[1|2]` doesn't return boolean, it returns a function that will return a `Boolean` provided you've given it an `Int`. There is one more level of indirection involved. If you write out the type of these functions entirely it will look like this: `Int => Int => Boolean`, or equivalently: `Int => Set`.

Coincidentally I wrote a blog post trying to explain how this works. You can check it out here:http://izmailoff.github.io/programming%20languages/functional%20programming/functional_sets. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

The `Set(elem)` refers to the companion object of `scala.collection.Set`, which is a *value*, and therefore is not shadowed by your `type`-definition `Set`.

Just run this to see it:

```
object devScript extends App {
  type Set = Int => Boolean
  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)

  def singletonSet1(elem: Int): Set = (x: Int) => x == elem
  def singletonSet2(elem: Int): Set = Set(elem)

  println(contains(singletonSet1(5), 5))
  println(contains(singletonSet2(5), 5))
  println(singletonSet2(42).getClass)
}
```

It will print `true`, `true`, `class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1`,
instead of something like `Int => Boolean`, as you might have expected.

Even more confusingly, the `contains(singletoSet2(5), 5)` also works, because, scala's standard collection `Set[A]` *also* implements `A => Boolean`, as can be seen [in the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Set.html).